# NEST: Add Term Query Under Condition

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In my application I pass a boolean parameter to a function that searches certain documents in my elastic index via a `HasChildQuery`. 
If this boolean is set to false I want to exclude documents with a specific field set, when the boolean is set to true I do not want this second condition.

This is my approach so far:

```
Query = new HasChildQuery                                         
{                                                                 
    // ...                               
    Query = new CommonTermsQuery                                  
    {                                                             
        // This Query always needs to be there  
        Field = Nest.Infer.Field<FaqQuestion>(q => q.Content), 
        Query = content                                   
    }                                                             
    && (includeAutoLearnedData ? null : +new TermQuery            
    {                                                             
        // I only want this Query if includeAutoLearnedData is false    
        Field = Nest.Infer.Field<FaqQuestion>(q => q.AutoLearned),  
        Value = false             
    })                                                            
}
```

My idea behind this is to always generate a request like this

```
has_child
|
|__ ...
|
|__ common_terms
```

and expand this to

```
has_child
|
|__ ...
|
|__ bool
    |
    |__must
    |  |
    |  |__common_terms
    |  
    |__filter
       |
       |__term
```

if `includeAutoLearnedData` is false. 
But the query for the case when it is true seems to not work.

I hoped that `&& (includeAutoLearnedData ? null : +new TermQuery` will add the filter only when the boolean is false and leave the query unmodified when it is true

So what is the correct way of including an additional filter query under a certain condition in NEST?

---

*EDIT*: 
I set a breakpoint when I get the result from my ElasticClient and expected it to have something like

```
Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /faq/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0770000
# Request:
{
    "query": {
        "has_child": {
             "bool": {
                 "must": [{
                     "common_terms": { ... }
                 }],
                 "filter": [{
                     "term": { ... }
                 }]
             }
         }
    }
}
```

but actual result had:

```
# Request:
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct and your approach is sound, but the reason you're seeing `{}` in the output is because of *conditionless* queries in NEST; Essentially, if a query does not have certain properties set (or they are assigned `null` or empty string), then the query is considered conditionless and not serialized as part of the request. For example, for a `term` query, if

1. the `field` has an empty string assigned to it, or a `null` string, expression or property
2. the `value` is `null` or an empty string

then the `term` query is considered conditionless. You can change this behaviour using [`verbatim` and `strict`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html)

#### `Verbatim`

Individual queries can be marked as verbatim meaning that the query should be sent to Elasticsearch **as is**, even if it is conditionless.

#### `Strict`

Individual queries can be marked as strict meaning that if they are conditionless, an exception is thrown. This is useful for when a query **must have an input value**.

To demonstrate that your approach works

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, new InMemoryConnection())
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .PrettyJson()
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .OnRequestCompleted(response =>
            {
                if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                        $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
            });

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var includeAutoLearnedData = false;

    var request = new SearchRequest<Message>
    {
        Query = new HasChildQuery
        {          
            Type = "child",
            Query = new CommonTermsQuery
            {
                Field = Infer.Field<Message>(m => m.Content),
                Query = "commonterms"
            }
            && (includeAutoLearnedData ? null : +new TermQuery
            {
                Field = Infer.Field<Message>(m => m.Content),
                Value = "term"
            })
        }
    };

    client.Search<Message>(request);
}

public class Message
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

produces the following query when `includeAutoLearnedData` is `false`

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "common": {
                "content": {
                  "query": "commonterms"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "content": {
                  "value": "term"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when it's `true`

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "common": {
          "content": {
            "query": "commonterms"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*(I noticed that we are missing a section on conditionless queries in the **[latest documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/index.html)**. Will add one!)*

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be clear that my queries are not empty. I thought their content would just add unnecessary clutter to my question that would not help anyone understand my question. I will edit my question